# Constructing rolling quarter-year data from date variable

Tags: sql-server, date, parameters

I have a dataset with individual records of Sales and Cancellations, identified by individual (ID) and date (Date). My goal is to construct a new table in which I aggregate the individual records to have the cancellation-share by individual, year, and quarter always for the past 12 months (i.e. for Quarter 1 in 2023 it is April 2022 to March 2023, for Quarter 2 in 2023 it is July 2022 to June 2023). The final data should look like this:

| ID | Year | Quarter | Cancellation-share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | 4 | X |
| 1 | 2023 | 1 | X |
| 1 | 2023 | 2 | X |
| 2 | 2022 | 4 | X |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have a SELECT-statement and work with a date parameter (@Today) that is set to 30th of June 2023, e.g.

```
SELECT ID, 1-(SUM(Sales-Cancellations) / SUM(Sales)) AS Cancellation-share
FROM Database
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, +1, DATEADD(Month, -12, @Today)) AND @Today
```

I considered to manually always go back by three months on the Between and AND Side, and alter the table to insert Year and Quarter manually, to finally UNION all constructed tables. However, this seems highly inefficient and error prone.

Since I wanna go back several years in time I want to write it dynamically and efficient. In the best case, I could state a min and max date, in between which the calculation is properly conducted to yield the desired results.

Unfortunately, I did not find threads that got me closer to a feasible solution for this specific setup.

I would be very thankful for any tips on how to tackle this, thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this it's very helpful to provide easily reproducible DDL/DML. This makes it easy for folks to help you. I like to use table variables for this as there's no clean up required. Consider:

```
DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (ID BIGINT IDENTITY, IndividualID BIGINT, Type NVARCHAR(1), Date DATE);
INSERT INTO @DataTable (IndividualID, Type, Date) 
SELECT TOP 500 ROUND(((10 - 1) * Rnd1 + 1), 0), CASE ROUND(((2 - 1) * Rnd2 + 1), 0) WHEN 1 THEN 'S' WHEN 2 THEN 'C' END,
       DATEADD(DAY,-ROUND(((730 - 1) * Rnd3 + 1), 0),GETUTCDATE())
  FROM (Values (RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1)), RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1)), RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1)))) a (Rnd1,Rnd2,Rnd3)
    CROSS APPLY sys.sysobjects z
    CROSS APPLY sys.sysobjects y;
```

This produces some random data which I think matches your description. It generates a Individual ID from 1 through 10, randomly decides if it should be a cancellation or a sale and a random date in the past two years.

You will likely want to use a calendar table or function. This will make it trivial to be able to group up your data. Consider:

```
SELECT c.Date, c.Year, c.Quarter, a.IndividualID, COUNT(CASE WHEN d.Type = 'S' THEN 1 END) AS Sales, COUNT(CASE WHEN d.Type = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS Cancels
  FROM Calendar(2,0) c
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT IndividualID FROM @DataTable) a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @DataTable d
    ON d.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(MICROSECOND,3,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,c.QuarterEndTime)) AND c.QuarterEndTime
    AND a.IndividualID = d.IndividualID
 WHERE c.Date = c.QuarterStartDate
 GROUP BY c.Date, c.Year, c.Quarter, a.IndividualID
 ORDER BY a.IndividualID, c.Date
```

| Date | Year | Quarter | IndividualID | Sales | Cancels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 3 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 1 | 7 | 3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 10 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 16 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 19 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 2 | 11 | 20 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 9 | 19 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 15 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 15 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 6 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 3 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 3 | 11 | 14 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 3 | 14 | 14 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 3 | 15 | 11 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 3 | 19 | 14 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 3 | 26 | 11 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 3 | 24 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 4 | 7 | 6 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 4 | 9 | 10 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 4 | 13 | 11 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 4 | 14 | 13 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 4 | 17 | 11 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 4 | 20 | 12 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 4 | 19 | 11 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 5 | 11 | 9 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 5 | 14 | 11 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 5 | 14 | 15 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 5 | 11 | 12 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 5 | 9 | 11 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 5 | 13 | 11 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 5 | 14 | 9 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 4 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 6 | 3 | 7 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 9 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 17 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 6 | 6 | 16 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 6 | 6 | 18 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 17 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 13 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 7 | 6 | 7 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 7 | 13 | 14 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 7 | 17 | 17 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 7 | 16 | 20 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 7 | 17 | 22 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 7 | 12 | 20 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 7 | 12 | 18 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 8 | 6 | 6 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 12 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 8 | 13 | 16 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 8 | 14 | 15 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 8 | 14 | 13 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 8 | 15 | 8 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 8 | 15 | 5 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 8 | 17 | 9 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 9 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 9 | 4 | 2 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 9 | 7 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 9 | 15 | 9 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 9 | 18 | 10 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 18 | 11 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 9 | 18 | 10 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 9 | 15 | 11 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 9 | 16 | 13 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021 | 3 | 10 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 4 | 10 | 4 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 10 | 6 | 5 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022 | 2 | 10 | 7 | 5 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022 | 3 | 10 | 5 | 3 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022 | 4 | 10 | 7 | 4 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | 1 | 10 | 8 | 3 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 2 | 10 | 8 | 4 |

If you don't have a calendar table/function here's an example of one. It accepts two INTs representing the number of years to go back and forward.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Calendar] (@StartYear INT, @EndYear INT)
RETURNS @Calender TABLE (
Date DATE, DateEndTime DATETIME2, Year INT, Month INT, Day INT, Quarter INT, WeekNumber INT, MonthName NVARCHAR(20), DayName NVARCHAR(20), WeekStartDate DATE, WeekEndDate DATE, MonthStartDate DATE, MonthEndDate DATE,
 QuarterStartDate DATE, QuarterEndDate DATE, YearStartDate DATE, YearEndDate DATE, WeekStartTime DATETIME2, WeekEndTime DATETIME2, MonthStartTime DATETIME2, MonthEndTime DATETIME2, QuarterStartTime DATETIME2, QuarterEndTime DATETIME2,
 YearStartTime DATETIME2, YearEndTime DATETIME2, IsWeekDay BIT) 
AS
BEGIN

WITH CalendarHistory AS (
SELECT CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE) AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,Date)
  FROM CalendarHistory
 WHERE DATEADD(DAY,-1,Date) > DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(YEAR,-@StartYear,GETUTCDATE())),1,1))
), CalendarFuture AS (
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1,GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE) AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)
  FROM CalendarFuture
 WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,Date) < DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(YEAR,@EndYear,GETUTCDATE())),1,1)
), Calendar AS (
SELECT Date
  FROM CalendarHistory
UNION ALL
SELECT Date
  FROM CalendarFuture
)

INSERT INTO @Calender
SELECT Date, 
       DATEADD(MICROSECOND,-3,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1,Date) AS DATETIME2)) AS DateEndTime,
       DATEPART(YEAR,Date) AS Year, DATEPART(MONTH,Date) AS Month, DATEPART(DAY,Date) AS Day, DATEPART(QUARTER,Date) AS Quarter, DATEPART(WEEK,Date) AS WeekNumber,
       DATENAME(MONTH,Date) AS MonthName, DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Date) AS DayName,
       DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date),Date) AS WeekStartDate, DATEADD(DAY,7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date),Date) AS WeekEndDate,
       DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY,Date),Date) AS MonthStartDate, DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY,Date),Date))) AS MonthEndDate,
       DATEADD(MONTH,(((DATEPART(MONTH,Date)-1)/3))*3,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date),1,1)) AS QuarterStartDate, DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,3,DATEADD(MONTH,(((DATEPART(MONTH,Date)-1)/3))*3,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date),1,1)))) AS QuarterEndDate,
       DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date),1,1) AS YearStartDate, DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date)+1,1,1)) AS YearEndDate,
       CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date),Date) AS DATETIME2) AS WeekStartTime, DATEADD(MICROSECOND,-3,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(DAY,7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date),Date)) AS DATETIME2)) AS WeekEndTime,
       CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY,Date),Date) AS DATETIME2) AS MonthStartTime, DATEADD(MICROSECOND,-3,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY,Date),Date))) AS DATETIME2)) AS MonthEndTime,
       CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,(((DATEPART(MONTH,Date)-1)/3))*3,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date),1,1)) AS DATETIME2) AS QuarterStartTime, DATEADD(MICROSECOND,-3,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEADD(MONTH,3,DATEADD(MONTH,(((DATEPART(MONTH,Date)-1)/3))*3,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date),1,1)))) AS DATETIME2)) AS QuarterEndTime,
       CAST(DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date),1,1) AS DATETIME2) AS YearStartTime, DATEADD(MICROSECOND,-3,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date)+1,1,1)) AS DATETIME2)) AS YearEndTime,
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date) IN (1,7) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsWeekDay
  FROM Calendar
 ORDER BY Date
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
 RETURN
END;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your great advice (and apologies for my poor problem description). Your advice has worked just perfectly, thanks to the calendar function, which I did not have otherwise. 

Two small questions in terms of clarification:
1)  CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT IndividualID FROM @DataTable) a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @DataTable d
-> Why do you split this in two steps? I directly merged the whole DataTable (that in my application was no parameter but a fixed table) and it worked as well.

2) Why does the grouping fail when not including c.Date as well? 

Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Tobi94 I wasn't sure exactly what your real data looked like. In the example I used there were multiple rows per individual, and I wanted to be sure we just got one per date. c.date would need to be grouped as well, since we're not applying an aggregate to it. That particular calendar function I wrote a while back, I should really publish it with a proper description some time. It's handy because it's so portable.